# How to create half wireframe using three.js library?

Tags: three.js, wireframe

I am using THREE.TubeGeometry() as following:

plannedtubeMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(plannedtube2, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
          { color: plannedcolor2, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: 1, wireframe: false, transparent: true,
              vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: false,opacity: 1.0
          }));

This gives me the tube with one side (back side), i.e. half tube but when I set wire-frame: true, the wireframe is complete circle instead of just one sided wire-frame. Is there any way to show only half (one side) wire-frame in three.js?

Comment: Could you post up a jsfiddle of this. The back side explanation has me confused. If your rendering a tube with {side: THREE.BackSide} then you are creating a whole tube, your just seeing through the "front" half. So it would reason that a wireframe would be the whole tube.